# Could powershell text output be passed to powershell cmdlet

Tags: xml, powershell, serialization, pipe, deserialization

Consider next powershell dialog:

```
> Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection

Name                  : VPN-StackoverflowQuestion
ServerAddress         : x.x.x.4
AllUserConnection     : True
Guid                  : {XXX2C9DE-58F0-41E4-XXXX-9809E90DCXXX}
TunnelType            : Pptp
AuthenticationMethod  : {Chap, MsChapv2, Pap}
EncryptionLevel       : Optional
L2tpIPsecAuth         :
UseWinlogonCredential : False
EapConfigXmlStream    :
ConnectionStatus      : Disconnected
RememberCredential    : False
SplitTunneling        : False
DnsSuffix             :
IdleDisconnectSeconds : 0
```

Such serialization looks nice and readable and editable. I can save it in a text file (dictionary) with

```
Get-VpnConnection > VPN-StackoverflowQuestion.dic
```

Now I want to pass this text file as args to `Add-VpnConnection`. Possible?

I know about `Export-Clixml`, it's result file is unreadable, uneditable and very cumbersome.

Comment: Hi, why go through a text file ? Why not pipe the first cmdlet's output to the next one directly ?

Comment: Because at first time I have no connections. Nothing to copy.

Comment: i write how to set vpn with this in my answers

Comment: Sure it's possible. You just need a function to convert the connection object to an INI style format and write that to a file, and another function to parse the information back from a flat file.

Answer (score 1):

yes use this command :

```
Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection |out-string | out-file "c:\path\filename.txt"
```

and u can parse this to return value .

another way :

```
 Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection |out-string | out-file "c:\path\filename.csv"
```

then you can return it into powershell

check this out i set my vpn like this :

```
$vpn = Get-VpnConnection
$vpn
$splitter = "SpliTtEr" #write custom string that you think unique 
$CustomStructure = $vpn.Name+$splitter+$vpn.ServerAddress+$splitter+$vpn.AllUserConnection+$SpliTtEr+$vpn.Guid ...


$CustomStructure | Out-File C:\path\filename.txt


$getcontent = Get-Content -Path C:\path\filename.txt


$items = $getcontent -split $splitter
Set-VpnConnection -Name $items[0] -ServerAddress $items[1] ...
```

Comment: You know how to return it as the powershell object?

Comment: @kyb : you need string ?

Answer (score 0):

The result is an object, export and save the object (CliXML, json) and when you need it convert the exported document into object again.